# How do I link/snap vertices or edges of two seperate objects with Shape Keys?

Tags: mesh, objects, vertices, shape-keys

So what I need to do is join the verticles along the edge of each body part (neck and torso) so that they stay together when I manipulate the vertices with Shape Keys (which I've already done, so ideally I would link them without losing the SKs).

I've tried making the head a child of the body but I've probably done it wrong as it has no effect that I can see.

Edit: In short, I'm trying to fix gaps between body parts that occur when using sculpt to create shape keys. Ideally I'd fix it systemically but if that's not possible then a quick way to fix each shape key would be perfect!

Many thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: It seems complicated, why don't you join the meshes into one object, and can't you work with less polygons?

Comment: Well I wanna keep them seperate because they are being exported seperately (for a modular character), but if the only way is to merge them and then seperate them again for export then I guess that's what I'll have to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can go edit mode with both objects -and shapekeys- selected and you should be able to edit to snap together both of their their meshes, drag select vertices or use proportional editing, pick two vertices and scale to zero, etc... also you could select the outer ring and propagate the basis shapekey... just some ideas